# What is the use of lit() in spark? The below two piece of code returns the same output, what is the benefit of using lit()

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two piece of codes here

```
gooddata = gooddata.withColumn("Priority",when(gooddata.years_left < 5 & (gooddata.Years_left >= 0),lit("CRITICAL"))).fillna("LOW").show(5)

gooddata=gooddata.withColumn("Priority",when((gooddata.Years_left < 5) & (gooddata.Years_left >= 0),"CRITICAL").otherwise("LOW")).show(5)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do you need to use lit() in Pyspark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715060/where-do-you-need-to-use-lit-in-pyspark-sql)

Answer (score 1):

For both spark and pyspark:

- literals in certain statements
- comparing with nulls
- getting the name of a dataframe column instead of the contents of the dataframe column

E.g.

```
val nonNulls = df.columns.map(x => when(col(x).isNotNull, concat(lit(","), lit(x))).otherwise(",")).reduce(concat(_, _))
```

from question: [Add a column to spark dataframe which contains list of all column names of the current row whose value is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127238/add-a-column-to-spark-dataframe-which-contains-list-of-all-column-names-of-the-c/62131213#62131213)

```
val df2 = df.select(col("EmpId"),col("Salary"),lit("1").as("lit_value1"))
```